# How To Disable Weak Cipher Suites Only For TLS 1.0 and 1.1 In Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-server-2012, https, cipher

I want to disable some weak cipher suites in Windows but TLS 1.2 is not so vulnerable and I don't want to cause any other problem in the server, so I just want to disable them for TLS 1.0 and 1.1.
`Disable-TlsCipherSuite` command works but disables a cipher suite for all TLS versions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 4):

Weak cipher suites should be disabled regardless of SSL/TLS version.

Also, yes: disabling versions of SSL/TLS older than TLS 1.2 is highly recommended.

IIS Crypto is a very useful free tool that will assist with disabling less secure protocols and cipher suites. See https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/.
Note: I am not in any way affiliated with Nartac Software. Simply recommending a GUI/command line tool that has proven to be very helpful.